# React Checking access from wrapper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to check user access from wrapper component before clicking on a button(or before a button onClick function fires).

Here is the button component

```
<UltimateButton
  btntext="+ New document"
  classes="btn-primary"
  handleClick={create_new_doc}
/>
```

Here `handleClick` fires onClick function (`create_new_doc`). And suppose I have a wrapper component `<AccessControl>` that wraps this button component. I want to check access when clicking `AccessControl` before `create_new_doc` is fired.

I wrote like this

```
import React, { Children, cloneElement } from "react";

const AccessControl = ({children}) => {
    const checkUserAccess = () => {
        console.log('Access denied')
    }

    return {...children}
}
export default AccessControl;
```

Now if access is denied in `AccessControl` then `create_new_doc` won't fire anymore. How can I accomplish it. I also tried clone element.

This will be used like this

```
<AccessControl>
  <UltimateButton
    btntext="+ New document"
    classes="btn-primary"
    handleClick={create_new_doc}
  />
</AccessControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways. If you want to keep a similar flow ( using access wrapper) then you should have the wrapper itself handle the on click to conditionally render the button.

**Here is one simple way to do this** (as aforementioned there are MANY ways to do this, let me know if you'd like a different version):

```js
import React from "react";

const AccessControl = ({ hasAccess, handleClick, children }) => {
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        if (hasAccess) {
            handleClick();
        } else {
            console.log('Access denied');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {hasAccess ? (
                children
            ) : (
                <button disabled onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                    Access Denied
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AccessControl;
```

**Usage**:

```js
<AccessControl hasAccess={checkUserAccess()}>
   <UltimateButton
     btntext="+ New document"
     classes="btn-primary"
     handleClick={create_new_doc}
   />
</AccessControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are on the right track with the idea of cloning the child component.

Clone the child component and re-inject a "decorated" `handleClick` prop that first makes a call to `checkUserAccess` and if this function returns true or confirms the user has access then it calls the originally passed `handleClick` callback.

Example:

```
const AccessControl = ({ children }) => {
  const checkUserAccess = () => {
    // Compute hasAccess
    console.log(hasAccess ? "Access allowed" : "Access denied");
    return hasAccess;
  };

  return Children.map(children, (child) =>
    cloneElement(child, {
      handleClick: (e) => checkUserAccess() && child.props.handleClick(e)
    })
  );
};
```

### Demo

```js
const AccessControl = ({ children, hasAccess }) => {
  const checkUserAccess = () => {
    console.log(hasAccess ? "Access allowed" : "Access denied");
    return hasAccess;
  };

  return React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, {
      handleClick: (e) => checkUserAccess() && child.props.handleClick(e)
    })
  );
};

const UltimateButton = ({ btntext, handleClick }) => (
  <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
    {btntext}
  </button>
);

const App = () => {
  const create_new_doc = () => console.log("create_new_doc");
  
   return (
    <div className="App">
       <UltimateButton
        btntext="No Access Control + New document"
        classes="btn-primary"
        handleClick={create_new_doc}
      />

      <AccessControl hasAccess>
        <UltimateButton
          btntext="Has access + New document"
          classes="btn-primary"
          handleClick={create_new_doc}
        />
      </AccessControl>

      <AccessControl>
        <UltimateButton
          btntext="No access + New document"
          classes="btn-primary"
          handleClick={create_new_doc}
        />
      </AccessControl>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```